# Cumulative probability distribution that better fits data plot

Tags: probability-distributions

I obtained this cumulative probability density plot of my data.
I tried normal distribution but found that it underestimates lower values between 2 to 6.

Is there a probability distribution that better fits such a data plot?

[image: data]

Comment: What about looking at a histogram of your data instead of the CDF?

Comment: @angryavian The empirical data is plotted using a histogram function on my data. I am seeking a suitable CDF as I want to apply it to other similar data to make a probabilistic estimation of the x values.

Comment: @angryavian Thanks. I found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821458/random-number-from-histogram) that you had suggested I explore. I have gotten the average approach to work but according to the NaomPeled the kde (kernel density estimation) of the histogram is a better approach. Will also be exploring that.